# AZindex related help needed

Tags: plugins

I want to display list of post in category page using [AZindex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/azindex/). So I've created a category template. Now I need help to display posts list by category there. For instance, when I'll go to domain.com/category/health, the page should display only post list from health category using azindex. Is it possible? I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom category template and [this](http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2010/12/03/template-to-list-posts-by-first-letter-of-title/) can help you.
All the best